# Why Gibbs free enthalpy is not zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

Referring to the first answer of this question

[Why does the Gibbs free energy need to be minimized for an equilibrium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341345/why-does-the-gibbs-free-energy-need-to-be-minimized-for-an-equilibrium)
$$dG=dE+pdV-TdS$$
But $dE=Tds-pdV$ so it should be $dG=0$. Why $dG$ is not always zero?

Comment: Also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599405/why-isnt-gibbs-free-energy-zero-freely).

Comment: This question keeps being asked and marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218068/why-is-gibbs-free-energy-not-equal-to-0-its-definition-itself-makes-it-0/218161#218161), which I answered. However, I find my answer unsatisfactory because it is incomplete in that it doesn't carefully discuss phase changes (although I mention it) or chemical reactions.  I'm wondering if some of our resident experts would be willing to post an answer to that question that is more complete (or edit mine, if that's reasonable). @Chemomechanics

Comment: @ChetMiller.  See my comment above. You or Chemomechanics would be a good choice to provide a more complete answer to the question.

Comment: @march I also would like to know what does it change if phase transition are considered

Comment: I don’t think the answer should be closed because I’m referring to the question that I linked that is about phase transition

Comment: The more general equation, unnecessary for single-component closed systems but necessary otherwise, including for phase changes, is $dE=T\,dS-P\,dV+\sum_i\mu_i\,dN_i$, where $\mu_i$ and $N_i$ are respectively the chemical potential and amount of component $i$. For a phase change, we have the additional constraint that $dN_1=-dN_2$. For constant temperature and pressure, therefore, we have $dG=(\mu_1-\mu_2)dN_1$, from which we deduce that phase changes occur at equilibrium when the chemical potentials of the phases are equal.

Answer (score 1):

This formula isn't universally valid.

Free enthalpy's definition is $G=E+PV-TS$, so, for a system without chemical reaction or phase transition:

$$dG=dE+PdV+VdP-TdS-SdT=VdP-SdT$$

So if $P$ and $T$ are constant, then yes, $dG$ will be zero.

Comment: Correct, provided there is no chemical reaction or chemical mixing.

Comment: @ChetMiller You're right, I added a few words about that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain me how a phase transition would affect this statement?

Comment: @SimoBartz Just a short answer (please open a new question if you want more details): in case of a phase transition or chemical reaction, additional terms appear in $dG$, involving chemical potentials of the subsystems.